# Oracle : Can a User change his own expired password?

Tags: .net, oracle

I have a .Net application. The application user is a database user.

When the database user's password expires, the user is not able to connect to the application (which is normal).

Currently when that happens, the DBA resets the password :

> ALTER USER user_name IDENTIFIED BY new_password;

Is there any way that the user changes his password without asking the DBA ? knowing that the application connects using OracleDataAccess library and if the password expires, the connection is not established.

Thanks,
Cheers

Comment: It is possible, but I believe that is a feature of the user interface. For example, SQL\*Plus allows the user to change her password **the first time** the user attempts to log in after password expiration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution : **OpenWithNewPassword**

Source : [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/featConnecting.htm)

```
    Dim con As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection()

Try
    con.ConnectionString = "User Id=testexpire;Password=testexpire;Data Source=oracle"
    con.Open()
    Console.WriteLine("Connected to Oracle" & con.ServerVersion)
Catch ex As OracleException
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)

    If ex.Number = 28001 Then
        Console.WriteLine(vbLf & "Changing password to panther")
        con.OpenWithNewPassword("panther")
        Console.WriteLine("Connected with new password.")
    End If

Finally
    con.Close()
    con.Dispose()
    Console.WriteLine("Disconnected")
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, however, the method they need to use will vary by the permissions the user has in the database and the software they have access to.

If an Oracle client is installed on the users system, they have SQL*Plus. Using SQL*Plus (or an application like `SQL Developer` or `Toad`,) they can connect to the database and do one of two things:

1. Issue the same `ALTER USER user_name IDENTIFIED BY new_password;` command that the DBA uses from the SQL*Plus prompt (assuming privileges have not been revoked.)
2. Issue a `password` command from the SQL*Plus prompt.

If for whatever reason they cannot use SQL*Plus and do not have access to other database management software, you can always build something custom that will allow them to change it via some other means. This AskTom article has some possible ideas to get you started: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6589437900346618270

Comment: Actually I was looking for something I can use from my application throught the library Oracle DataAccess :) ! You imagine if your Messenger app password expires and asks you to open a black screen SQL Plus to change the password ? How would your application appear :) ?

Comment: Got it! And unfortunately yes - I help support a lot of legacy apps, so only having to open command prompt and starting a SQL*Plus session would be a welcome change :/ Nevertheless, glad you figured out a better solution that works for you!